# Bulma nesting column

Tags: html, semantic-markup, bulma

How can I mark up this on Bulma? I'm trying to use this code below but I need to limit the first column will only have 2 boxes inside then it will go down from left to right. In Bootstrap this will just be easy but in Bulma, it compressing the nested column in just one line.

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor">
 <div class="tile is-4 is-vertical is-parent">
  <div class="tile is-child box">
    <p class="title">One</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tile is-child box">
    <p class="title">Two</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile is-parent">
  <div class="tile is-child box">
    <p class="title">Three</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use columns

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=columns>
    <div class="column is-6">
      // map is here
    </div>
    <div class="column is-6">
      <div class="columns is-multiline">
        <div class="column is-6">
          // image is here
        </div>
        <div class="column is-6">
          // image is here
        </div>
        <div class="column is-6">
          // image is here
        </div>
        <div class="column is-6">
          // image is here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `columns` layout, so that you can use the `is-mobile` modifier. Something roughly like:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-half">
      <div class="columns is-mobile">
        <div class="column is-half">
          <div class="box">
            <figure class="is-128x128">
              <img src="http://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-half">
          <div class="box">
            <figure class="is-128x128">
              <img src="http://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="columns is-mobile">
        <div class="column is-half">
          <div class="box">
            <figure class="is-128x128">
              <img src="http://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-half">
          <div class="box">
            <figure class="is-128x128">
              <img src="http://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-half">
      <figure class="is-480x480">
        <img src="http://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x480.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
```